# Running chrome in --no-sandbox mode using chimp.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chimp.js

Is there a way to tell chimp to run chrome outside the sandbox while using chimp + mocha + selenium?

I read in their website that most of the configuration can be done through the command line, but I was unable to find a list of possible arguments in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

## Here are the list of options:

As per their docs on https://chimp.readme.io/docs/command-line-options

> See the [default Chimp configuration file](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/blob/master/src/bin/default.js) for the available options. You can provide any of the options in that file via the command-line also by prefixing the listed option with --.

### Full list of options as on 1st Jan 2017

Check the default config file above to stay up to date
Following are the list of options with their default values:

```
// - - - - CHIMP - - - -
 watch: false,
 watchTags: '@watch,@focus',
 domainSteps: null,
 e2eSteps: null,
 fullDomain: false,
 domainOnly: false,
 e2eTags: '@e2e',
 watchWithPolling: false,
 server: false,
 serverPort: 8060,
 serverHost: 'localhost',
 sync: true,
 offline: false,
 showXolvioMessages: true,

 // - - - - CUCUMBER - - - -
 path: './features',
 format: 'pretty',
 tags: '~@ignore',
 singleSnippetPerFile: true,
 recommendedFilenameSeparator: '_',
 chai: false,
 screenshotsOnError: isCI(),
 screenshotsPath: '.screenshots',
 captureAllStepScreenshots: false,
 saveScreenshotsToDisk: true,
 // Note: With a large viewport size and captureAllStepScreenshots enabled,
 // you may run out of memory. Use browser.setViewportSize to make the
 // viewport size smaller.
 saveScreenshotsToReport: false,
 jsonOutput: null,
 compiler: 'js:' + path.resolve(__dirname, '../lib/babel-register.js'),
 conditionOutput: true,

 // - - - - SELENIUM  - - - -
 browser: null,
 platform: 'ANY',
 name: '',
 user: '',
 key: '',
 port: null,
 host: null,
 // deviceName: null,

 // - - - - WEBDRIVER-IO  - - - -
 webdriverio: {
   desiredCapabilities: {},
   logLevel: 'silent',
   // logOutput: null,
   host: '127.0.0.1',
   port: 4444,
   path: '/wd/hub',
   baseUrl: null,
   coloredLogs: true,
   screenshotPath: null,
   waitforTimeout: 500,
   waitforInterval: 250,
 },

 // - - - - SELENIUM-STANDALONE
 seleniumStandaloneOptions: {
   // check for more recent versions of selenium here:
   // http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
   version: '2.53.1',
   baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com',
   drivers: {
     chrome: {
       // check for more recent versions of chrome driver here:
       // http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
       version: '2.25',
       arch: process.arch,
       baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
     },
     ie: {
       // check for more recent versions of internet explorer driver here:
       // http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
       version: '2.50.0',
       arch: 'ia32',
       baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com'
     },
     firefox: {
       // check for more recent versions of gecko  driver here:
       // https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
       version: '0.11.1',
       arch: process.arch,
       baseURL: 'https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download'
     }
   }
 },

 // - - - - SESSION-MANAGER  - - - -
 noSessionReuse: false,

 // - - - - SIMIAN  - - - -
 simianResultEndPoint: 'api.simian.io/v1.0/result',
 simianAccessToken: false,
 simianResultBranch: null,
 simianRepositoryId: null,

 // - - - - MOCHA  - - - -
 mocha: false,
 mochaCommandLineOptions: ['--color'],
 mochaConfig: {
   // tags and grep only work when watch mode is false
   tags: '',
   grep: null,
   timeout: 60000,
   reporter: 'spec',
   slow: 10000,
 },

 // - - - - JASMINE  - - - -
 jasmine: false,
 jasmineConfig: {
   specDir: '.',
   specFiles: [
     '**/*@(_spec|-spec|Spec).@(js|jsx)',
   ],
   helpers: [
     'support/**/*.@(js|jsx)',
   ],
   stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: false,
   random: false,
 },
 jasmineReporterConfig: {
   // This options are passed to jasmine.configureDefaultReporter(...)
   // See: http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/node.html#section-Reporters
 },

 // - - - - METEOR  - - - -
 ddp: false,
 serverExecuteTimeout: 10000,

 // - - - - PHANTOM  - - - -
 phantom_w: 1280,
 phantom_h: 1024,
 phantom_ignoreSSLErrors: false,

 // - - - - DEBUGGING  - - - -
 log: 'info',
 debug: false,
 seleniumDebug: null,
 debugCucumber: null,
 debugBrkCucumber: null,
 debugMocha: null,
 debugBrkMocha: null,
```